# When is it safe to block in an Akka 2 actor?

Tags: akka

I know that it is not recommended to block in the `receive` method of an actor, but I believe it can be done (as long as it is not done in too many actors at once).

[This post](http://letitcrash.com/post/29773618510/an-akka-2-terminator) suggests blocking in `preStart` as one way to solve a problem, so presumably blocking in `preStart` is safe.

However, I tried to block in `preRestart` (not `preStart`) and everything seemed to just hang - no more messages were logged as received.

Also, in cases where it is not safe to block, what is a safe alternative?

Answer (score 1):

It's relatively safe to block in `receive` when:

1. the number of blocked actors in total is much smaller than the number of total worker threads. By default there are ten worker threads, so 1-2 blocked actors are fine
2. blocking actor has its own, dedicated dispatcher (thread pool). Other actors are not affected

When it's not safe to block, good alternative is to... not block ;-). If you are working with legacy API that is inherently blocking you can either have a separate thread pool maintained inside some actor (feels wrong) or use approach 2. above - dedicate few threads to a subset of actors that need to block.

Comment: That's a good explanation. I think the main point is that blocking uses up a thread. Too much blocking slows your program down. You should always try to use non-blocking operations.

Answer (score 1):

Never ever block an actor.

If your actor is part of an actor hierarchy (and it should be), the actor system is not able to stop it.
The actor's life-cycle (supervision, watchig etc.) is done by messaging.
Stopping a parent actor of a blocking child will not work.

Maybe there are ways to couple the blocking condition with the actor's lifecycle.
But this would lead to overload of complications and bad-style.

So, the best way is to do the blocking part outside of that actor.
E.g. you could run the blocking code via an executor service in a separate thread.

Comment: Well, it will work when the blocking operation has finished, successfully or unsuccessfully. Obviously there would be a problem if it blocks forever. That's the kind of problem I had in my original situation.

Comment: If you block an actor for seconds, your actor will become unresponsive. Restarts or application shutdown will freeze for that time. This contra-productive to the idea of failure-tolerance.

Comment: I actually want my application shutdown to block, so that the persistent state on disk can catch up with what's in memory.

Comment: It is too easy to get blocked for a long time. So I suggest writing software to embrace errors. To do this, the actors should cope in any second with stop messages.